# Is this Unicorn publicly available?

Tags: support, unicorns

I am not sure that this is the right place to ask or if there is a place to ask this question, but a few minutes ago I clicked a [SO.Careers ad](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/products?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=ad&utm_campaign=employers-superheroes&utm_content=sb-superheroes) on StackoverFlow.com and came about this picture:

[image]

Long story short: I need one because of reasons! Actually I want two. One for my daughter and one for my desk. One would suffice - I can put up a photo of her holding it.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216179/where-can-i-get-a-unicorn

Comment: Darn, didn't look on StackExchange Meta. My bad.

Comment: For shame! Nah, just knew it had come up at some point.